# How to get a client without freezing the Windows Forms App C# WindowsPCL

Tags: c#, wordpress, asynchronous, task, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to grab post data from my website to use in a windows forms app. When I try to call the method below to get a WordPressClient of my website, the whole form freezes and doesn't respond.

```
public static async Task<WordPressClient> GetClient()
        {
            //JWT authentication
            var client = new WordPressClient("http://website.com");
            client.AuthMethod = AuthMethod.JWT;

            //Form freezes on this line
            await client.RequestJWToken("email", "password");

            return client;
        }
```

Comment: What does the method look like where you call `GetClient()`? Is it async too?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the internal logic happening there,
but try wrapping the call for the `WordPressClient` constructor into a `Task.Run`:

```cs
public static async Task<WordPressClient> GetClient()
{
    try
    {
        WordPressClient client = null;

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //JWT authentication
            client = new WordPressClient("http://website.com");
            client.AuthMethod = AuthMethod.JWT;
        });

        //Form freezes on this line
        await client.RequestJWToken("email", "password");

        return client;
    }
    catch (Exception e) // this should be more specific Error Handler
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Also, please make sure that the code that is running `GetClient()` is running it with `async`:

```cs
var client = await GetClient();
```

Comment: This doesn't compile, and is more suited to being a comment than an answer.

Comment: you initialized the client inside the (await Task.Run()) so (await client.RequestJWToken("email", "password") can't access client since it's a local variable. Also I think the problem is when I use the await operator at all. Any method that I use with the await operator freezes the app

Comment: @zaidiqbal, that was a stupid mistake by me, sorry, just fixed. About the `await` operator: it by no means can freeze anything because what it is doing is telling the Foreground thread to release until the asynchronous operation will complete. That's being said I'm not sure that wrapping the initialization with `Task.Run` itself will help, but you can try checking if the constructor call is actually taking a lot of time or not.